# Conditional formatting depending on value in previous cell

Tags: google-sheets, formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a column with following values:

```
336.1
329.2
420.5
332.1
12.9
639.6
531
461.9
...
```

I'd like to apply conditional formatting to the whole column with a rule that adds red background if a *previous* value was bigger and green background if the value was lower.

I'm using *new* google spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conditional formating, select "Custom Formula Is", select the Range, and apply the formulas based on the first cell of the Range.

Eg.

Rule 1:
Range: A5:A50, Custom Formula, =A5>A4 -> Green Background

Rule 2:
Range: A5:A50, Custom Formula, =A5< A4 -> Red Background

For multiple columns separate ranges with commas, Eg. A5:A50,B5:B50,C5,C50.

Comment: I swear I did exactly that and it didn't work. I did it again and it works :) Thanks :)